# Updating a hook without calling the set updater method in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

What would happen if a react hook's state is updated directly instead of calling the set updater function.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        gender: "",
        dob: "",
        contact: "",
        institute: "",
        institute_other: "",
        occupation: "",
        occupation_other: "",
        street_address: "",
        city: "",
        division: "",
        country: "",
        email: "",
        user_name: "",
    });

  const [username, setUserName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
}
```

> This is the hook that I have initialized

In an input handler function I am updating a certain element in the state variable object directly like this --

```
// ... My other codes

formData.division = "some_Division";
formData.city = "some_city";

// ... Rest of the code
```

This happens to update my state object.
But I definitely understand that this is not a good practice, but can I get a clarification about how it breaks the rule of hooks in react and what problems it might pose in the future (if it may).

N.B: I have tried to update the state in this way inside the input handler function but with no luck!

```
const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    switch (e.currentTarget.name) {
      case "country":
        setUpdateDivision(true);
        setUpdateCity(true);
        setDivisionHook("");
        setCityHook("");
        setFormData((formData) => ({ ...formData, division: "", city: "" }));
        setDivisionOptions([]);
        setCityOptions([]);
        console.log(e.currentTarget.selected);
        break;
      case "division":
        setUpdateCity(true);
        setCityHook("");
        setFormData((formData) => ({ ...formData, city: "" }));
        setCityOptions([]);
        break;
      case "institute":
        setUpdateInstitute(true);
        break;
      case "occupation":
        setUpdateOccupation(true);
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }

    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [e.currentTarget.name]: e.currentTarget.value,
      email: email,
      user_name: username,
    });
  };
```

It does not update the state variable.

> Edit: I have added the complete handleInputChange function for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with updating the state directly is that is a mutation and won't trigger React to rerender a component with the updated state value. It's not breaking the "Rules of Hooks", it's breaking React's rule against state/props mutations.

See [Using State Correctly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly)

> ### Do Not Modify State Directly
>
> For example, this will not re-render a component:
>
> ```
> // Wrong
> state.comment = 'Hello';
> Instead, use setState():
>
> // Correct
> setState({comment: 'Hello'});
> ```

I suspect your enqueued state updates aren't working due to a stale enclosure. Using a functional state update resolves this by updating from the previous state versus the state closed over in scope. This also helps if you are enqueueing several state updates within the same enclosure where each update needs to update from the previous result.

```
setFormData(formData => ({
  ...formData,                                   // shallow copy previous state
  [e.currentTarget.name]: e.currentTarget.value, // update property
}));
```

### Update

Another issue is that enqueued React state updates are not immediate. They are enqueued (*think of this as a request to React to "please update state X with value Y at your earliest convenience"*), and batch processed asynchronously. When you update with `setFormData` several times and don't use a functional update then each update overwrites the previously enqueued update when it's processed using the current state value of the enclosure over what is passed in the updater function.

Comment: But using the updater method does not modify the state. What may cause the problem?

Comment: @JoyRamSenGupta It's not clear why the state update isn't updating your state (*other than possible mutations*) from your code snippet, perhaps you've omitted important details in the `//..... rest of the code` comments, or not fully explained the use case in `handleInputChange`? It sort of looks like you may also be trying to enqueue several state updates, is this correct?

Comment: Yes there are other state updates apart from the formData state. I have changed formData only in the handleInputChange based on the switch case branching. and finally at the end of the handleInputChange function which updates the formData based on the event.currentTarget

Comment: I have updated the handleInputChange function for more clarity. I am not sure what is causing the problem.

Comment: @JoyRamSenGupta So what *specifically* isn't updating and how are you determining this?

Comment: As you may see, If I change country field in a select option input that should clear the formData's division and city elements. but Its not clearing it. However, setting new city and division through their respective select option does update formData.division or formData.city. I have determined that using logging it in console and also checking that using component viewer by React developer tools extension for Chromium/Chrome/Edge in dev tools.

Comment: @JoyRamSenGupta Other than that last `setFormData` which ***doesn't*** use a functional update (*it's overwriting the previous updates*), I see no issue with the others and they follow the suggestion of my answer of using functional state updates. Try fixing that last `setFormData` to use a functional update (* and any others that don't*) and see if that clears the issue up.

Comment: The portion which does not use functional update at the end of handleInputChange seems to work fine. But the updater inside the switch case block fails to update formData.  Functional update in the end of the inputHandleChange poses a new problem, it doesnot recognize 'e' as it is in a new scope. passing e along with formData doesn't help and throws error, saying e is undefined .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239330/discussion-between-joy-ram-sen-gupta-and-drew-reese).

Comment: Thanks. Solved the issue. As you said the setFormData is updating the previous updates,, I moved that to the top and over switch...case branch, and it solved the issue. I have also changed the inner updaters with functional updates, except the one I moved to the top. [Solved]